# FXMLLoader getController() returning null

Tags: java, controller, fxml, fxmlloader

So I'm new to JavaFx and programming in general, and I'm having a problem where I cannot get a fxml file Controller into my program. Here's the Code

```
@FXML
private void handleBtnAdicionarAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {   
    Stage adicionarStage = new Stage();
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/AdicionarWindow.fxml"));
    Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    adicionarStage.setScene(scene);
    adicionarStage.centerOnScreen();
    adicionarStage.show();
    awUI = loader.getController();
    System.out.println(awUI);
    awUI.associarController(this);
}
```

After I do this the field awUI should contain the Controller of the file I'm loading but it comes out null... I've been doing other projects where I do this method and it's been working I don't know what may be Wrong here. Can someone Help me with this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using IntelliJ mark your resources directory, by right clicking on the *resource* folder, selecting Mark Directory as -> Resources Root. Inside your *resources* folder there should be an fxml containing your **AdicionarWindow.fxml** file. 
If not using Intellij please check on how your IDE works with Resources folder.

For more information on intellij click [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html).